# Como imprimir/exportar (pdf, xls, impressora) os gráficos do google chart?

Tags: google-charts, exportação

Criei uma tela com vários gráficos usando o google charts, mas estou precisando imprimir/exportar para pdf, xls, impressora, só que de tudo que eu procurei na net ainda não achei nada, será que alguém sabe de alguma forma de como eu poderia fazer isso?

A partir do exemplo mais básico, será que alguém consegue me dar uma luz?!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você quer imprimir somente o #piechart? Já tentou "@media" e window.print?

Comment: Eu preciso imprimir tanto o #piechart quanto outros elementos que tenham como titulos e textos, mas nesse exemplo que passei seria somente o grafico gerado mesmo. E nao tentei ainda usar os @media, sera que tem algum exemplo para o caso? Valew

Answer (score 1):

Você fala exportar para "impressora", realmente isto não faz sentido para mim, mas vou supor que você simplesmente quer imprimir com <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> ou que o dialogo de impressão do navegador seja chamado diretamente.

Se for realmente isto, então você pode simplesmente chamar o `window.print()`:

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work',     11],
        ['Eat',      2],
        ['Commute',  2],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}

document.getElementById("print").onclick = function() {
    window.print();
};
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<button id="print">Imprimir</button>
```

Você também pode usar o `@media` para ocultar todos elementos (acaso o seu chart esteja em uma página com "várias coisas") e imprimir. Ficaria algo como:

```
@media print {
    body {
         visibility: hidden;
    }

    #piechart {
         visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Porém também posso presumir que talvez você queira dizer outra coisa como "exportar para impressora", talvez você só queria realmente exportar com a intenção de gerar um documento como PDF, mesmo na parte que você fala de impressora, então a solução seria o [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

Para usar o jsPDF com SVG (o seu Chart é um SVG :) ) provavelmente terá que usar o plugin [sillysvgrenderer](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.plugin.sillysvgrenderer.js) (está no próprio repositório). Um exemplo de como adicionar o SVG com o plugin seria:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var chart = document.querySelector("#piechart svg");
var sourcecode = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(chart);

//Adiciona o SVG
doc.addSVG(sourcecode, 15, 15);

//Download do arquivo
doc.save("sample-file.pdf");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, vou dar uma olhada e ainda volto a falar se deu certo ou não e dai sinalizar como resposta válida. E quando eu digo imprimir quero dizer que se der para exportar para um pdf, excel, imagem, qualquer coisa que de para o usuário exportar já esta bom, então vou fazer uns testes, e imprimir (windown.print) não da muito certo pois se eu tiver muitos graficos ele pode quebrar algum no meio da página.

Comment: Se o que você quer dizer com imprimir é exportar então `window.print` não é a resposta. A resposta é `jsPDF`.