# Como exportar uma DIV com gráficos para PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Alguem tem algum codigo javascript que exporte uma div com grafico para um arquivo .PDF?

Comment: até onde sei, e com minhas experiências anteriores nisso, só dá pra fazer isso com PHP!

Comment: se souber como utilizar veja isso: http://pdfkit.org/

Comment: Vlw pela resposta @LeandroRuel, só uma duvida, esse pdfkit pode criar um pdf a partir de uma DIV? por que os exemplos que tem nesse site ele cria tudo na mão.

Comment: opa @sergioBertolazo não testei apenas busquei alguma coisa para você dar uma olhada, tem que ler a documentação melhor, se não suprir sua necessidade, procure por "javascript pdf generator"

Comment: é cara eu testei nao funfo msm.. @LeandroRuel , vlw pela ajuda ai cara vo ter que continuar a procura pra fazer isso funcionar

Comment: amigo, qual plugin de gráfico esta usando na página html?

Comment: @LeandroRuel eu estou utilizando o Chart.js

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como imprimir/exportar (pdf, xls, impressora) os gráficos do google chart?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49734/como-imprimir-exportar-pdf-xls-impressora-os-gr%c3%a1ficos-do-google-chart)

Comment: Já tentou usar  a biblioteca do [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depois de um tempo pesquisando e quebrando a cabeça sobre essa questão, consegui criar um script usando [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) para criar um gráfico simples e então exportei esse gráfico para PDF usando o [jsPDF.js](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), porém para ser possível passar o gráfico para o pdf, teria que antes disso transformá-lo em uma imagem em formato PNG, para realizar essa tarefa utilizei o plugin [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html). eis o fiddle com o script que usei: https://jsfiddle.net/tj9tsyc3/5/

html:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<button type="button">gerar pdf</button>
```

js:

```
 $('button').on('click', function(){
      html2canvas($('#myChart'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
          pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
          pdf.save('test.pdf');
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta @Leandro Ruel, funcionou perfeitamente pra mim, só que somente no Google Chrome, Firefox, IE 10 e 11, no IE 9 está dando erro, vou tentar achar um jeito de conseguir, valeu pela ajuda irmão!

Comment: disponha! qualquer coisa so comentar aqui